# iFrame links doesn't work

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, soundcloud, facebook-iframe

I've created a Ruby on Rails app which is located at heroku, you can check it here "http://soundcloud-dj-contest.herokuapp.com/"

App is working perfectly and I've placed it inside the iFrame on facebook so it should work like facebook app. 
Every link is working beside this  button on top "Logirajte se da uploadate". This link leads to another page, soundcloud "soundcloud-dj-contest.herokuapp.com/login".

It works on main page but inside an iFrame I can't get it to work. I don't know what to do :/

I've uploaded iFrame here http://facemaskbliss.com/test/test_frame.html

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try putting `target="_blank"` and also giving the full path instead of just "/login"

Comment: you can also try this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe_name

Comment: If I put target="_blank" it opens in new tab and after authentication it leads me to main website, not in a iFrame inside facebook.

I've also tried to put a full path, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @DeniMartić did you try the other thing in the comment above

Comment: The problem is much more bigger then i tought. I can't even create an iFrame with this link "www.soundcloud-dj-contest.herokuapp.com/login"

Comment: Please check what did I wrote and test it before you answer. I've used code without www  "<iframe src="http://soundcloud-dj-contest.herokuapp.com/login" 

"></iframe>" 
And it doesn't work.

Comment: for some reason you can't put your login page in iframe. i dont know why. http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/uQfxa/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a link inside an iFrame. I was using the absolute url ("http://example.com").

I finally got it to work by using the relative path to the page ("../example_folder/").

My guess is that for security reasons "foreign" links using **https** are "disarmed" now in iFrames, even if they are on the same domain. Because the link (absolute url) works when not using **https**.

Edit: Now that I think of it is because I was mixing **http** and **https**.